# Error: [cache-manager] memcache driver not specified

Tags: node.js, memcached, nestjs

I have a node project built with nestjs. I am trying to set up Memcached but get an error that the driver is not specified. I have Memcached installed locally and the server started with `memcached -d`

This is what I have in my modules import

```
import {CacheModule} from '@nestjs/common';
import * as memcachedStore from 'cache-manager-memcached-store';
import Memcache from 'memcache-pp';


@Modules({
   imports: [
       CacheModule.register({
            store: memcachedStore,
            driver: Memcache
            options: {
                hosts:['127.0.0.1:11211']
            }
       })
   ]
///
})
```

How do I specify driver?

Answer (score 1):

use: import * as Memcache from 'memcache-pp';